# Where to report issues of OpenJDK when you're not a OpenJDK developer?

Tags: java, issue-tracking

First I thought it's strange that there's no link to a bug tracker on the [OpenJDK project page](http://openjdk.java.net/), then I found [bugs.openjdk.java.net](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/), but it's only for accredited project members. How do people outside the ivory tower contribute issues? There's the mailing list and some people call sending issues and patches to a mailing list bug tracking... but the development and usage of bug tracker contradicts.

Comment: Similarly:  how do we add information to an existing bug report?  Several times I've seen an older OpenJDK bug closed with "cannot reproduce" while I'm sitting there with a perfect test case, but no way to contribute anything to the now-closed bug.  It's very discouraging.

Comment: It's a pretty crappy situation. Until it's fixed, I have a few workarounds. Post them to discuss@openjdk.java.net (or a better mailing list) or if you are using a linux distro, file it against your distribution's bug tracker. Often we have access to openjdk's bug system.

Comment: [This has been discussed on the OpenJDK mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2015-December/003840.html) as well.

Comment: https://bugreport.java.com/ (based on the link supplied by Karl Richter)

Comment: @omajid At this point it will never be fixed, because it's not in Oracle interests to have a good working open source project competing with it's own products and services. That's why OpenJDK need to get their own foundation and git repo and issue tracker. This is getting annoying to a point where it's basically mismanagement and neglectance

Comment: [The bug submission FAQ list](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/faq.do#faq-10) also refers to [the OpenJDK mailing lists](https://mail.openjdk.org/mailman/listinfo). I don’t know in which situations one is preferred over the other.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to http://bugs.java.com or jump straight to the report page:    http://bugreport.java.com/

My interpretation of their [FAQ](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/faq.do) is that this will be triaged by an Oracle engineer, and if accepted it will be assigned a number and (usually) become visible in both Oracles + the OpenJDK bug databases.

*It would be **really** helpful if this info/link were on the OpenJDK bug page too. The database split is already confusing enough - when your goal is to contribute to **OpenJDK** but you find yourself at an Oracle-branded page, it seems like you've gone to the wrong place.*

UDPATE (Nov 2019): To add **Additional information** to a bug ([FAQ](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/faq.do) point 6):

> File a new incident with the subject line "Additional information to JDK-XXXXXXX'. Replace XXXXXXX with the reference number received when the report is filed. We are working on a system where you will be able to provide additional information to the existing bug.

---

Now, if you're curious who can get *direct* access to the bug database...

From (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/):

> Everyone with OpenJDK **Author** status or above has a [JDK Bug System] account which may be used to create and edit bugs. Those without accounts can view bugs anonymously.

To understand that, you need to navigate the various "role" definitions:

http://openjdk.java.net/bylaws#author

From Section 7:

> An **Author** for a Project is a Contributor who has been granted the right to create changesets intended to be pushed into a specific Project’s code repositories, but does not have the right to push such changesets directly.

From Section 2:

> A **Contributor** is a Participant who has signed the Oracle Contributor Agreement (OCA), or who works for an organization that has signed that agreement or its equivalent and makes contributions within the scope of that work and subject to that agreement. A Contributor may submit changes larger than a simple patch, may propose new Projects, and may take on various roles within Groups and Projects.

and ...

> A **Participant** is an individual who has subscribed to one or more OpenJDK mailing lists. A Participant may post messages to a list, submit simple patches, and make other kinds of small contributions.

So the bar is set pretty high. `:-/`

Comment: I wanted to submit a bug.. read all that and found myself mumbling "mmm... is this 2005?" feeling a growing urge to jump off a bridge..

Comment: .. and three years later here I am again, trying to upvote my own comment.. "why can't I upvode this comment?..oh, right, I wrote it"

Comment: I was searching for https://bugreport.java.com/ URL, and this answer was too long without providing the actual URL.

Comment: @AndreaVacondio aaaaand now we're almost in 2024, nothing has changed :D

Answer (score 20):

I wanted also to report a bug and the only place I could find is the following one:

http://bugreport.java.com/

I hope it is the correct place, Oracle engineer might end up creating an issue in the bugs.openjdk.java.net if it happen to be really an bug.

Hope this helps

Comment: That seems to be for the Orcale JDK (!= OpenJDK).

Comment: OpenJDK is used as base of the Oracle JDK no ? and in their form I could find selection for the package where I wanted to submit

Comment: @KarlRichter No. I can tell you from personal experience (having filed hundreds of bugs over the years) that any bugs you report here will get applied against both OpenJDK and OracleJDK.