# Unsure of how to proceed on reporting a possible bug in OpenJDK

Tags: java

I am running a Minecraft server using [Spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org/) on Fedora 29 64-bit with OpenJDK 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13) and receive the following exception when executing a particular command:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: record_overflow
   at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:129) ~[?:?]
   at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[?:?]
   at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308) ~[?:?]
   at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279) ~[?:?]
   at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181) ~[?:?]
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164) ~[?:?]
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1155) ~[?:?]
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125) ~[?:?]
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:823) ~[?:?]
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252) ~[?:?]
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292) ~[?:?]
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351) ~[?:?]
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:746) ~[?:?]
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689) ~[?:?]
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:717) ~[?:?]
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1604) ~[?:?]
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509) ~[?:?]
   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245) ~[?:?]
   at org.bukkit.command.defaults.TimingsCommand$PasteThread.run(TimingsCommand.java:240) [spigot-1.13.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:git-Spigot-f56e2e7-1748af8]
```

This is a `javax.net.ssl.SSLException` and appears to be related to the OpenJDK. The error does not appear when using Oracle JVM.

I don't have an easy way to provide a working example for a bug report and the source files for Spigot must be obtained through a lengthy process of downloading several git repositories and executing a script which then builds the patched .java files. I can't even provide snippets myself as I [haven't been able to get it to build](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/build-source-fails-with-error-sha1-information-is-lacking-or-useless.357959/).

Where would be an appropriate place to report this and how can I go about doing it in such a way that is useful to the OpenJDK developers. This does appear to be a problem with this source code but I'm unable to provide even the smallest bit of code outside of this exception.

Comment: The are several actions you could take to report a bug to the OpenJDK developers. Even just file an bare-minimum bug report on their Bug Tracker website and link extra information to this Question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: But before filing a new bug, best to check if the same bug has already been reported. Looking at `hub.spigotmc.org` isn't your bug similar to the bug reported here:  https://hub.spigotmc.org/jira/browse/SPIGOT-4449?workflowName=Jira+Fixed&stepId=1 ?

Comment: @davedwards As indicated by the embedded links in my question, I did provide my initial bug report to the Spigot bug tracker and was told that it cannot be reproduced and is most likely a bug in OpenJDK. I confirmed this likelihood by running the command on an Oracle JVM.

Comment: Do you have an OpenJDK JBS account? If so, file a bug at http://bugs.openjdk.java.net/ Otherwise, it seems non-developers file bugs on http://bugreport.java.com/ ref: [Where to report issues of OpenJDK when you're not a OpenJDK developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379425/where-to-report-issues-of-openjdk-when-youre-not-a-openjdk-developer)